# A / B testing without seperate deployments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am part of a development team producing a project which requires many rounds of iterative development, each of which must be user tested, frequently in an A/B kind of environment.

In our deployment environment it's not straightforward for us to deploy side by side versions at the moment so I was interested if anyone had suggestions for sensible ways to handle multiple iterations (predominantly UI) of an application within the same codebase.

At the moment we're enduring multiple `.cshtml` views for the alternative UI's but the further we go, the more changes we're needing to make to accommodate the changes (e.g. multiple routes, controller actions which are just duplicated).

Beyond separate deployments how have people catered for this kind of situation elsewhere? interested in any `do`'s and `don't`s

Comment: By users you mean clients, or is this a piece of software used internally to your company?  I'm crossing my fingers hoping for the latter, because if not, this approach is not sustainable in the long run..

Comment: Maybe add areas to your MVC app and when the session is first established set a session variable to decide which area to use?

Comment: @Neil It's a bit of both, we don't anticipate needing to run the testing post release and the user testing will be conducted in controlled internal environments but the users performing the testing will be real world users.

Comment: @GregBurghardt that's an idea, we'd be happy to use a querystring parameter or similar to determine the version and send out differing URLs to the testing group

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Granted, you make me think most problems would be of the graphic variety and therefore not serious problems like crashes, but this is going to create a lot of unwanted finger pointing from the client who claims they understand what it means to test an unfinished product but don't really understand all that entails.

Comment: @Neil this is certainly a risk, but mandated for us at the moment. Fortunately we do have an experienced user researcher who will be putting things in context for all the users involved. Some of our users will be internal and part of and organisation and some external public users.  

Perhaps I should have clarified the 'user testing' side of things. By this I mean we will be putting different versions of a screen in front of the users and assessing their feedback on preferences and ease of use, rather than using them to test functionally for bugs etc.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to test version A of the whole application against version B of the whole application? Or do you want to A/B test many smaller changes independently? (So say the contact form, checkout process and product lookup of a web shop all three have two versions and the end user can mix&match whatever permutation they want to test.)

Comment: @JoryGeerts we are aiming to test isolated areas at the moment. Many of the areas are well defined and are covered by previous rounds of user testing so we can safely implement these without needing to prove the testing aspect. It's mainly the newer areas where we need to move away from the previous implementation where we are mandated to demonstrate user testing to support the design decisions.